# different position on dynamically changing arrays having html elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures

React/Javascript developers please help
I am trying to create a video conference app with 4video track 2*2 grid and the remote tracks are in an array. The array gets updated when someone opens the same website or disconnect from it.
the feature I need is that the position of all the video tracks should be fixed.
We have 4 places of video. Let users are 1, 2 ,3 and 4
I want user 1 always to be shown at top left corner
User 2 always at top right
User 3 always at bottom left
User 4 always at bottom right.
Positions of the users will be same on every system.
Another example:
If only user 1 and user 4 are connected with each other then position of the videos will be like:
User 1 at top left corner
User 4 at bottom right corner

Comment: please give more information about the component you are trying to apply this logic to. Give us some HTML example and/or some JS

Answer (score 0):

You will need a way to tell if a user is connected in your array. You can do this by either setting the array element to `null` when they disconnect or by including a `connected` flag in the user data.

Now when you render the users, just check if the user is connected. If they are not connected, render a placeholder. Otherwise render the video stream.